# NGINX proxy_pass or proxy_redirect

Tags: nginx

Need help on Nginx proxy_pass.

From outside Nginx URL will be hit like this: 
http://some-IP:8080/v2/platform/general/activity/plan?.....

my downstream service looks like this:
http://another-IP:8080/activity/plan?...

I want to get rid of

> /v2/platform/general

from original public url and call my downstream service like above.

In Nginx, how do I redirect public access URL to downstream service?

I tried this:

```
location /v2/platform/general/ {
  rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://another-IP:8080;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

But it didn't work, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`proxy_pass` and `proxy_redirect` have totally different functions. The `proxy_redirect` directive is only involved with changing the `Location` response header in a 3xx status message. See [the NGINX proxy_redirect docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for details.

Your `rewrite` statement does nothing other than prevent further modification of the URI. This line needs to be deleted otherwise it will inhibit `proxy_pass` from mapping the URI. See below.

The `proxy_pass` directive can map the URI (e.g. from `/v2/platform/general/foo` to `/foo`) by appending a URI value to the `proxy_pass` value, which works in conjunction with the `location` value. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

For example:

```
location /v2/platform/general/ {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://another-IP:8080/;
}
```

You may need to set the Host header only if your upstream server does not respond correctly to the value `another-IP:8080`.

You may need to add one or more `proxy_redirect` statements if your upstream server generates 3xx status responses with an incorrect value for the `Location` header value.

Comment: Great!!. This Just saved me the extra pain of debugging.